# gnu-parallel - Weird behavior when handle multiple arguments

Tags: gnu-parallel

Im using GNU Parallel version 20170322 and got some extrange behaviors when i try to use multiple arguments. For example `parallel echo ::: A B C ::: 1 2 3` return 

`A 1
A 2
B 1
B 2`

as expected, but `parallel echo {} and {} ::: A B ::: 1 2` return

`A 1 and A 1
A 2 and A 2
B 1 and B 1
B 2 and B 2`

and `parallel echo {1} and {2} ::: A B ::: 1 2` 

`1 and 2 A 1 
1 and 2 A 2 
1 and 2 B 1 
1 and 2 B 2`

I tried to reinstall or even use a Rust fork but i have the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parallel echo {} and {} ::: A B ::: 1 2` does as designed: Inserting {} twice.

Your shell is probably teasing you (Maybe you are using tease-sh (tcsh)). Try:

`parallel echo '{'1} an'd {2}' ::: A B ::: 1 2`

Comment: With `zsh` this works: `parallel echo '{1} and {2}' ::: A B ::: 1 2`